# Кто автор фразы?

Tags: фразеология, литература, история, источники

"Наши привычки - это расплата за наши ошибки". Который день не могу припомнить источник. "Зеркальная" фраза понятна и афористично скучна, а здесь нечто в духе Уайльда либо экзистенциалистские глубины. Возможно, Шестов. Но не приснилось же это...

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите найти автора?

Comment: Короче, задайте новый вопрос или утвердите предложенный вариант. Хотя я совсем не уверен, вас вас поняли правильно.

Comment: Может быть, это "Единственное, о чем никогда не пожалеешь, это наши ошибки и заблуждения". Афоризмы Уайльда см.: https://ru.wikiquote.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%A3%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4

Answer (score 2):

*— Но я не хочу, чтобы вы повторили прежнюю ошибку.

— Никакой ошибки я не совершаю — я оставляю позади свои прежние ошибки.

— Вы хотите оставить позади самое себя, но это невозможно. Чем больше вы стараетесь убежать от себя, тем вернее остаетесь собой.*
(Фрэнсис Скотт Фицджеральд)

***Мыслите сами, избегая чужого влияния. И если вы совершите ошибку, не страшно: ведь даже ошибки подчеркивают вашу индивидуальность.***
(Бернар Вербер)

*Я заметил одну интересную вещь: продвигаясь по великой дороге жизни, ты всё время делаешь одни и те же чёртовы ошибки. Точно могу сказать, что все свои ошибки ты повторишь в будущем.*
(Гор Видал)

*Мы те, кем мы являемся: мы лгуны, мы воры, мы зависимые, мы не ценим своё счастье, пока не навредим себе или кому-то другому... Мы жалеем, и, осознав свои ошибки, мы переделываем прошлое, переделываем себя, по крайней мере пытаемся... Мы гордые, похотливые, далеко не идеальные.., и в итоге наши недостатки берут вверх над нами.*
(из фильма "Холм одного дерева")

***Ничто так не говорит о нас и нашем характере, как те ошибки, которые мы порой совершаем.***
[(**персонаж Макс Пейн**)](https://4lit.net/search?ask=%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8&page=2)

P.S. "Ваша" цитата,  @glyptus, какая-то "ненаходительная"! Я попыталась предложить Вашему вниманию что-то похожее; ***особо близкое по смыслу*** - как ***мне*** кажется - я отметила.

Answer (score 0):

Мысль на мой вкус довольно ординарная.
Возможно, вольный перевод римского Consuetudo est altera natura (Привычка – вторая натура).